# Two players alternately name dates

Tags: strategy, game, word-problem

Two players alternately name dates. The winner is the player who names 31st December, and the starting date is 1st January. If a player names Xst of Y Month, the other player can name the first of the next month (1st of Month Y+1) or the next day of the current month (X+1 of Month Y). (For example, the first player begins by naming 1st February or 2nd January). How would one make a strategy for this game?

Answer (score 9):

If the first player is the one who says either 2nd January or 1st February, then the winning player is

> the second player

Proof:

> The player who says 31st December wins, so the player who says any odd date in December wins, so 1st December also wins.

> Therefore, the player who says any November date loses (because the next player can say 1st December).

> Therefore, the player saying 31st October wins, so all odd dates in October (also 1st October) win.

> So any September date loses.

> So 31st August wins, odd dates in August win, and 1st August wins.

> So any July loses.

> So 30th June wins, even dates in June win, 2nd June wins, 1st June loses.

> So 31st May wins, odd dates in May win, and therefore 1st May wins.

> Any April date loses.

> So 31st March wins, as do all odd dates in March, and therefore 1st March wins.

> Any February date loses.

> 31st January wins, odd dates in January win, so 3rd January wins, and 2nd January loses.

The first player

> can only say 2nd January or 1st February, which both lose. Therefore, the second player wins.

The strategy is to

> go to the line in which I discussed the current month, and say the next winning date.

**Note:** I assumed that the game only goes over one year. If players can go on to the next January, then

> the game will never end. The reason is that there is no date that forces the next player to say 30th December.